# How to retrieve text from text box after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, submit, postback

I have some textbox's who's values are all empty when i try retrieve there values from the behind code after a post back submit.

My submit button:

```
<ICCM:ICCMImageButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnResSubmit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" PostBack="true" style="float:right; padding-right:5px;" TabIndex="23"/>
```

Behind C# code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//code
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = txtFName.Text.ToString();
//more code
}
```

Page load:

```
btnSubmit.ClickScript = "if(ValidatePage() == false){return false}; this.disabled = true; document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('ControlID') + 'Text').innerHTML = '" + Resources.ICCMCPortal.Submitting + "';";
```

OnInt:

```
btnSubmit.Page = this.Page;
```

---

The text value is always "" unless i pre populated the textbox in the page load then the text will be that regardless if i made a change to it.

Comment: Check if you are initiliasing the text box to `""` on page load

Answer (score 1):

Set you textbox values inside here:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      SetTextboxValues();
   }
}
```

This way the wont be reset on postback.